# path to all folders and subfolders in c/windows/

Tags: windows

I need a list that show me the path to every single folder and subfolder located in c/windows/ on my computer.

Is there a way i can do this easy from command prompt and export, or something similar. maybe a easy .bat script i can use to extract what I need ?

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Open command prompt, type `dir /?`. Then:

- `dir /B /S /A:D c:\windows\` could suffice to display unhidden folders.
- `dir /B /S /A:DH c:\windows\` displays hidden folders.

To export output to a file `anyname.txt`:

```
dir /B /S /A:D c:\windows\>anyname.txt
dir /B /S /A:DH c:\windows\>>anyname.txt
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- [Script resources for IT professionals](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=ProgrammingLanguage&f%5B0%5D.Value=VBS&f%5B0%5D.Text=VB%20Script&f%5B1%5D.Type=RootCategory&f%5B1%5D.Value=storage&f%5B1%5D.Text=Storage&f%5B2%5D.Type=ProgrammingLanguage&f%5B2%5D.Value=Windows%20Shell%20Script&f%5B2%5D.Text=Windows%20Shell%20Script&f%5B3%5D.Type=ProgrammingLanguage&f%5B3%5D.Value=PowerShell&f%5B3%5D.Text=PowerShell) (a huge Script repository)